# How to discard Backspace key press event in Textfield in Flutter (Web)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am creating a Flutter web app. The requirement is that under certain condition I have to block user from pressing backspace (or delete key) while typing some text in Textfield. I have tried `RawKeyboardListener` and  `TextEditingController`. They help me listening the keyboard events, but I am unable to modify or discard keyboard events.

```
RawKeyboardListener(
    focusNode: focusNode,
    onKey: handleOnKeyEvent,
    child: TextField(
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
        controller: textEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Start typing here'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        minLines: null,
        maxLines: null,
        expands: true,
        onChanged: (value) {
           //print('text = $value');
           handleUserInput(value);
         },
      ),
  ),
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a way better solution but can't you add the last letter every time backspace is pressed?

Comment: handleOnKeyEvent definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a `TextController` to check if text has been backspaced?

In this way the user can still type new characters but **cannot delete them**.

```
late String initialText;
late TextEditingController _textController;

void initState() {
  initialText = "MyText";
  _textController = TextEditingController(text: initialText);
  super.initState();
}
```

and inside the `build()`:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _textController,
  onChanged: (input) {
    if (_textController.text.length < initialText.length) {
      _textController.text = initialText;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        initialText = _textController.text;
      });
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: If the user cuts that part of the text, the code doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

For me, the `TextField.onChange()` and `TextController` callback were not worked.

After a bit of searching, I got this GitHub answer by **Sonu-simon**

> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14809#issuecomment-907617733

Basically, It says to wrap TextField with the `RawKeyboardListener` widget. It has an `onKey` callback with `RawKeyEvent` passed in as a param.

I used it and it worked for me.

```
if (value.data.logicalKey.keyLabel == "Backspace") {
    // stuff here...
}
```

In answer, Sonu-Simon explained to use the `keyId` property(to verify the backspace pressed), but it is different for each platform I think. So I have used the `keyLabel` property.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, it seems impossible to listen to backspace keyboard tap.

My solution to trigger onChanged of TextField when field is empty is to use an invisible char :

```
const String invisibleChar = '\u200B';
```

Giving this as default value of a text editing controller

```
TextEditingController(text: invisibleChar);
```

If you work with obscure text pin, it could lead to bad behaviour like showing obscure symbol for this invisible char. Solution is to obscure only if controller's value is no invisible char :

```
TextFormField(
  obscureText: controller?.text != invisibleChar
)
```

Don't forget, if the field had a value and then become empty again with the backspace button, you should reinitialize the value to the invisibleChar :

```
controller?.addListener(() {
  if (widget.controller?.text.isEmpty ?? true) {
   controller?.text = invisibleChar;
   onBackspaceTap?.call(); //do your action on backspace tap
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Focus(
      onKey: (node, event) {
        if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
          print('backspace');
          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        }
        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      }
      child: TextField(
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
        controller: textEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Start typing here'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        minLines: null,
        maxLines: null,
        expands: true,
        onChanged: (value) {
          //print('text = $value');
          handleUserInput(value);
        },
      ),
    )
```

Returning `KeyEventResult.handled` in `onKey` represents intercepting the input event.

Refer to: [https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/interactivity/focus#:~:text=)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Key%20events,-If%20you%20wish](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/interactivity/focus#:%7E:text=)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Key%20events,-If%20you%20wish)